# Script not prompting for input variables when executing through root for oracle user

Tags: sh

I am executing one shell script through root user, this script is further calling  other script in oracle user. My pain is that i am unable to see prompt instruction for to put inputs, Could you please help.

Regards,

Comment: Can you add bit more information here

Comment: there is script wrapper.sh, will be getting executed by root. second script get_details.sh will be executed on oracle. please find sample script as below :[#!/bin/bash
#set -xv
stty echo
echo "user is : " $whoami
echo " "
echo "Enter Host here : $@"
read _Hosts
echo " "
echo "Enter Files details :\c"
read _DC
echo " "
echo "Enter username :\c"
read _USR
echo " "
echo "Enter password :\c"
read _pass
echo "executed all...!"
echo " "
echo "Print Host :" ${_Hosts}
echo " "
echo "Print File :" ${_DC}
echo " "
echo "Print User :" ${_USR}
echo " "
echo "Print pass :" ${_pass}]

Comment: #!/bin/bash

#set -xv
stty echo
echo "user is : " $whoami
echo " "
echo "Enter Host here : $@"
read _Hosts
echo " "
echo "Enter Files details :\c"
read _DC
echo " "
echo "Enter username :\c"
read _USR
echo " "
echo "Enter password :\c"
read _pass
echo "executed all...!"
echo " "
echo "Print Host :" ${_Hosts}
echo " "
echo "Print File :" ${_DC}
echo " "
echo "Print User :" ${_USR}
echo " "
echo "Print pass :" ${_pass}
~

Comment: #!/bin/bash
set -xv

echo $(whoami)

if [[ $(whoami)  = 'root' ]]
then
  echo $SHELL
  #$(sudo su - oracle) > /check/log.log 2>&1
  . /check/check_test.sh > /check/log.log 2>&1
  exit;
fi

Comment: try using this sudo -i -u user whoami